# How can I open WeChat Scanner with Deeplink?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, mobile-browser, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I tried with `weixin://scanqrcode`. It opens with iPhone devices. But didn't work with Android device.

I tried with `weixin://dl/scan` as well. But it gives me error. It might be deprecated.

Actually, I'd like to open WeChat Official Account with any browsers.

I don't know if there is a way to directly go to my official account with this deeplink - `weixin://dl/officialaccounts`. If there is, How can I get the official account's ID? and how to add the paramater? Such as... `weixin://dl/officialaccounts/Ej139dzcljsd`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've been searching for the same thing, have you had any luck? :)

Comment: @Lauren Unfortunately, no.